# Whats the best method to create this list with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm new to the world of PHP and looking to see if there is a better way of writing this little code snippet that I have. Basically, it gives variables for some social media links, checks if they are empty, creates an array in a function and I call the array in a UL. I know its simple but I'm just looking if what I have is best or if I can improve on it any.

```
    <?php

    $facebook  = of_get_option('facebook');
    $twitter   = of_get_option('twitter');
    $youtube   = of_get_option('youtube');
    $linkedIn  = of_get_option('linkedin');
    $instagram = of_get_option('instagram');

    $socialMediaLinks = array(

    );

    if (!empty($facebook)){
        $socialMediaLinks[facebook] = $facebook;
    }
    if (!empty($twitter)){
        $socialMediaLinks[twitter] = $twitter;
    }
    if (!empty($youtube)){
        $socialMediaLinks[youtube] = $youtube;
    }
    if (!empty($linkedIn)){
        $socialMediaLinks[linkedIn] = $linkedIn;
    }
    if (!empty($instagram)){
        $socialMediaLinks[instagram] = $instagram;
    }

    function socialMediaList($value, $key){
        echo '<li class="'.$key.'"><a href="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</a></li>';
    }

    ?>

    <?php if (!empty($socialMediaLinks)){ ?>
    <ul class="social-media">
        <?php array_walk($socialMediaLinks, 'socialMediaList'); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Looking good **but** loops can save you lines of code.
You can do the `get_option` and `!empty(..` checks in a loop instead of writing it.

Comment: You should start by fixing the errors. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script.

Comment: IMO you should get all your options in one unique array (with a kinda "global of_get_optionS" function, then work on it instead of getting these options individually and then put it into an array... ex. : foreach($options as $media){//checks...}, I don't think that using !empty is really important here since if it is really empty, it is not displayed...

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten the code by simply doing:

```
$socialMediaLinks = array_filter(array(
   'facebook' => of_get_option('facebook'),
   'twitter' => of_get_option('twitter'),
   'youtube' => of_get_option('youtube'),
   'linkedIn' => of_get_option('linkedIn'),
   'instagram' => of_get_option('instagram'),
));
```

This will automatically remove all empty entries, so you won't need that whole bunch of if-statements afterwards.

Comment: Would you keep the function or at that point just use a foreach loop?

Comment: Personally, I prefer the style of using a foreach loop and echo '<li>...'; It's a short and clear solution, whereas if you use array_walk you'll have to search this function in your code first. But this is really just up to your preferred style. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $socialMediaItems = array(
        'facebook' => of_get_option('facebook'),
        'twitter' => of_get_option('twitter'),
        'youtube' => of_get_option('youtube'),
        'linkedin' => of_get_option('linkedin'),
        'instagram' => of_get_option('instagram')
    );
    $socialMediaLinks = array();

    foreach ($socialMediaItems as $key => $item) {
        if ($item) {
            $socialMediaLinks[$key] = $item;
        }
    }  

    function socialMediaList($value, $key){
        echo '<li class="'.$key.'"><a href="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</a></li>';
    }

    ?>

    <?php if (!empty($socialMediaLinks)){ ?>
    <ul class="social-media">
        <?php array_walk($socialMediaLinks, 'socialMediaList'); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array

```
<?php

    $facebook  = of_get_option('facebook');
    $twitter   = of_get_option('twitter');
    $youtube   = of_get_option('youtube');
    $linkedIn  = of_get_option('linkedin');
    $instagram = of_get_option('instagram');

    $socialMediaLinks = array();
    $madeArray = array('facebook' => $facebook,'twitter' => $twitter,'youtube' => $youtube,'linkedin' => $linkedIn,'instagram' => $instagram);
    foreach ($madeArray as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
              $socialMediaLinks[$key] =  $value;
            }
    }
    function socialMediaList($value, $key){
        echo '<li class="'.$key.'"><a href="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</a></li>';
    }

    ?>

    <?php if (!empty($socialMediaLinks)){ ?>
    <ul class="social-media">
        <?php array_walk($socialMediaLinks, 'socialMediaList'); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better can be:

```
<?php
    $socialmedia = array('facebook', 'twitter', 'youtube', 'linkedin' 'instagram');

    $socialMediaLinks = array();

    function GetOptions($name)
    {
        $value = of_get_option($name);
        if (!empty($value))
            $socialMediaLinks[$name] = $value;
    }

    foreach ($socialmedia as $smname)
        GetOptions($smname);

    function socialMediaList($value, $key){
        echo '<li class="'.$key.'"><a href="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</a></li>';
    }
    if (!empty($socialMediaLinks)){ 
?>
    <ul class="social-media">
        <?php array_walk($socialMediaLinks, 'socialMediaList'); ?>
    </ul>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd made something like this:

```php
$social_networks = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'youtube', 'linkedin', 'instagram'];
$media_links = [];

foreach ($social_networks as $network) {
    if ($option = of_get_option($network)) {
        $media_links[$network] = $option;
    }
}

// your code to output...
```

If you write simple application with short support time - your displaying style its normal. But if it something complex, you should look to MVC pattern.